# @@OpenCount And DBCC OpenTran

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

Can you Explain what is difference between this two statement:

1)select @@trancount

2)DBCC opentran

when I Use TransactionScope in C# Statement No.1 return 0 but No.2 return Result.

when I Use begin Tran in sql server No.1 return 1 but No.2 return nothing.

what is difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

FRom [@@TRANCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx)

> Returns the number of BEGIN
>   TRANSACTION statements that have
>   occurred on the current connection.

and from [DBCC OPENTRAN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182792.aspx)

> Displays information about the oldest
>   active transaction and the oldest
>   distributed and nondistributed
>   replicated transactions, if any,
>   within the specified database.

Comment: thanks but Can you Explain this words shortly:"oldest active transaction" and "oldest distributed and nondistributed replicated transactions".In MSDN for DBCC OPENTRAN writed:Use DBCC OPENTRAN to determine whether an open transaction exists within the transaction log.I don't unserstand difference between word "transaction" in here and @@trancount